# Python path on VS Code on macOS

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, python-3.7

I'm configuring VS Code on macOS to work with Python.

I installed Python 3.7 and configured everything with the help of the [VS Code tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

So far it seems to work fine but when I debug some Python code on VS Code Terminal it returns this output:

`iMacdiVincenzo:hello antedoro$ cd /Users/antedoro/Desktop/hello ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/antedoro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.7.1/pythonFiles/PythonTools/visualstudio_py_launcher_nodebug.py /Users/antedoro/Desktop/hello 52047 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput /Users/antedoro/Deskto p/hello/hello.py Hello World`

I think there is problem with the `PATH` variable. How I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think there's an issue with your `PATH`? That output looks accurate based on the standard debug launch configuration.

Comment: I see other VS Code configuration and there is no this output.

Comment: I think people are just leaving it out of their examples. The output you're seeing is entirely expected.

Comment: It is very annoying. However, OK